# Remove CR, LF, tabs -- except in <pre> and <code>

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'd like to remove all the CR, LF and tabs in an HTML string, except when they exist in `<pre>` and `<code>` (assuming they are properly closed. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: You should probably walk the DOM, using [PHP's built-in DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [a 3rd-party one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net), skipping `pre` and `code` tags, and applying your replacement to every text node you find.

Comment: The DOM would "correct" missing tags, improper nestings, etc. So, if I were to work on the DOM, my result could be much different than the original HTML minus the CR, LF, and tabs.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Why would you ever want to deal with invalid HTML? Also, what should the regex do if not dealing with improper nesting of <pre> and <code> tags?

Comment: Invalid HTML is a reality of the web. What to do if the <pre> and <code> if they aren't properly closed? Don't treat them any different. The exception should only be between `<code></code>` and `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: Maybe you can find a parser that keeps a (character) offset to the original source? Then you can find the text between the right tags and replace them in the original source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried playing around with regex assertions for a while but I don't think it's possible that way as PHP doesnt seem to let me use wildcards in the lookahead/lookbehind matches.

**Edit** 
The previous example wasnt going to work with nested elements inside pre & code. This will let you capture the spacings you want to keep, remove all spacing, then put the desired spacing back in:

```
//$html is your initial html string with line returns and spaces

//pattern to match open tag, inner content and closing tag
$pattern = '/<(pre|code)((?!<\/?\1).)*?<\/\1>/s';

//before: capture the string pattern of the multiline elements
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $before);

//remove all LF, CR and indentation tabs
$html = preg_replace('/(\t|\r|\n)/s', '', $html);

//after: capture the string pattern of the condensed elements
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $after);

//loop through the matches to replace the after with the before
foreach($after[0] as $k => $v){
    $html =  str_replace($v, $before[0][$k], $html);
}
```

if the tags are improperly closed, they won't fit the match pattern and thus will be skipped and have spacing stripped.